# Как добавить контакты в файл contacts2.db (контакты Android)?

Tags: android, sql

Есть стандартная база контактов на Android устройстве, я хочу в нее добавить еще контактов. Открываю данную базу компьютере через SQL Lite выполняю инсерт:

```
insert into raw_contacts (display_name, display_name_alt, sort_key_alt,sync1) values    (89000000000,89000000000,89000000000,89000000000);
```

После чего, новая строка появляется в `raw_contacts` при переносе базы обратно на телефон в контактах нового контакта не отображается. Что я делаю не так?